# how to connect oracle database using remote desktop in SOAP UI?

Tags: automated-testing

I have been trying long time to do this.
My organisation uses remote desktop to connect through Oracle database.

I am using ready API licence one.my problem is while trying JDBC connection in SOAP or READY API, it cant connect.could you let me know, what driver needs to be isnatlled at ready api so that i can set up with remote desktop or what configurations needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tunnel connections through a remote desktop session. Ask for a VPN connection or install SoapUI on the remote desktop machine.